# How can I enable breakpoint debugging in Visual Studio for JavaScript files served from a separate project in a .NET Core MVC solution?

Tags: javascript, c#, visual-studio, asp.net-core-mvc

I'm working on a .NET Core MVC web app in Visual Studio 2022, consisting of two relevant projects:

- Project 1: The main web app, where I can set and hit breakpoints in JavaScript files without issues
- Project 2: A supporting C# project included in the solution, containing vanilla JavaScript files that I'm actively developing

I serve JavaScript files from Project 2 in Project 1 via a custom static files configuration, but encounter issues when setting breakpoints in these files directly within Visual Studio; they show as "unbound breakpoints." Setting breakpoints in the browser's DevTools for these files works, and they trigger breaks in Visual Studio normally.

Here's a short snippet of my custom static files implementation:

```
        public static IApplicationBuilder UseStaticFilesCustom(this WebApplication app)
        {
            var env = app.Environment;

            var staticAllowedExtensions = new[] { ".png", ".jpg", ".gif", ".svg", ".ico", ".ttf", ".woff", ".woff2", ".js", ".css", ".map" };

            var allowedFiles = new[] { "manifest.json" }; // files that we need to allow to bypass the above list
            const string cacheMaxAge = "604800";

            var dllPath = Path.Join(Path.GetDirectoryName(Assembly.GetEntryAssembly()!.Location), "projectDllNameHere");
            var embeddedProvider = new ManifestEmbeddedFileProvider(Assembly.LoadFrom(dllPath), "/Static");

            app.UseStaticFiles(new StaticFileOptions()
            {
                FileProvider = embeddedProvider,
                RequestPath = "/Static",
                OnPrepareResponse = ctx =>
                {
                    var fileName = ctx.File.Name.ToLower();
                    var fileExtension = Path.GetExtension(fileName);

                    if (!staticAllowedExtensions.Contains(fileExtension) && !allowedFiles.Contains(fileName, StringComparer.OrdinalIgnoreCase))
                    {
                        Debug.WriteLine($"ERROR: Attempt to download {ctx.Context.Request.Path}");

                        ctx.Context.Response.StatusCode = 407; // Not Found
                        return;
                    }

                    ctx.Context.Response.Headers.Append("Cache-Control", $"public, max-age={cacheMaxAge}");
                }
            });

            return app;
        }
```

I don't use any external JavaScript bundlers or compilers — just the built-in Visual Studio debugger. It seems like Visual Studio isn't correctly mapping the JavaScript files from Project 2 back to their source, preventing me from setting breakpoints from directly within VS.

Is there a workaround/solution to this?

Comment: Is the project type ASP.NET (framework) or ASP.NET Core? And Debug or Release?

Comment: @MinxinYu-MSFT it’s an ASP.NET Core web project running in Debug.